# Volterra operator is completely continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ on the borelians, and consider the Volterra operator $V:L^1[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ given by
$$
Vf(t)=\int_0^t f d \mu
$$
So, I want to show the following

> **Proposition:** The Volterra operator sends weak compact sets into norm compact sets.

I've already proved that this operator sends uniformly integrable sets into uniformly bounded and equicontinuous sets of $C[0,1]$, i.e, relatively compact sets in $C[0,1]$. I know that uniformly integrable sets are the same that relatively $\omega$-compact sets. I don't get how to finish the problem with this.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: put $F= V ({ball}~~ L^1)$, show that $F$ is bounded and equicontinuous. Then using Arzela - Ascoli theorem $V$ is compact. by a proposition every compact operator is completely continuous.

Comment: @niki Thx for the answer, but I can't see directly that $V(B_{L^1})$ is equicontinuous. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added: The discussion below shows that $V$ is *not* a compact operator.
However, since $L^1$ is *not* reflexive, this does not preclude that $V$
is completely continuous.  (See e.g. [the wikipedia discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Completely_continuous_operators).)

To show that $V$ is completely continuous, one approach is to show that
if $f_n$ is a sequence which converges to $0$ weakly in $L^1$,
then $V(f_n)$ converges to $0$ in $C[0,1]$, i.e. $V(f_n)$ converges to zero uniformly.

Since the dual to $L^1$ is $L^{\infty}$, to say that $f_n$ converges to zero
weakly is the same as saying that for any $L^{\infty}$-function $\phi$,
the integrals $\int f_n \phi$ converge to zero.

Since $Vf(t) = \int f \chi_{[0,t]} $ (where $\chi_{[0,t]}$ is the indicator
function of the interval $[0,t]$, which is in $L^{\infty}$),
we see that $Vf_n$ converges to zero pointwise.

But actually, the rate of convergence to zero of $\int f_n \phi$
depends only on $|| \phi ||_{\infty},$ so as long as e.g. $||\phi ||_{\infty} \leq 1$,
the sequence $\int f_n \phi$ converges to zero uniformly in $\phi$ (i.e. for any
$\epsilon > 0$, we can find a value of $N$
such that  $| \int f_n \phi| < \epsilon$ *for every* $\phi$ s.t. $|| \phi ||_{\infty} \leq 1$).

(The reason for this is that the sequence $f_n$ is norm-bounded in $L^1$
(being weakly convergent; see e.g. [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/241604/170324)), and hence equicontinuous
on the unit ball of $L^{\infty}$, when we think of the elements
of $L^1$ as functionals on this unit ball.  An equicontinuous sequence
 which converges pointwise to zero in fact converges uniformly to zero; see
e.g. [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649588/170324)
(note that the argument goes over for compact spaces that are not necessarily
metrizable)
or [the wikipedia discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Equicontinuity_and_uniform_convergence),
and note that the unit ball of $L^{\infty}$ is compact in the weak-$*$ topology,
by the [Banach--Alaoglu Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem).)

This shows that convergence of $V f_n$ to zero is uniform, as required.

---

There's something that confuses me about this statement.  I will try to explain
my confusion.  Hopefully it will help with your question.  If not, I apologize.
[Added: my confusion came from the fact that being completely continuous
is weaker than being compact, when the domain is not reflexive.]

---

[Added: the following discussion shows that $V$ is not compact.]

Suppose that $g \in C[0,1]$ is actually differentiable and monotone increasing,
that $g(0) = 0,$ and that $g(1) = 1$.

Then if we set $f = g'$, then $f \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$ (by the mononicity assumption),
and $$|| f ||_1 = \int_0^1 f = \int_0^1 g' = g(1) - g(0) = 1.$$
And of course $V f = g$ (again using the fact that $g(0) = 0$).

So all these $f$ have $L^1$-norm equal to $1$, and so we would be saying that
any sequence of such $g$'s has a convergent subsequence (since they all lie in 
the image of $V$ applied to the unit ball in $L^1$).

But this is not true.

For example, take $g_n(t) = t^n,$ so the corresponding $f$ is
$f_n(x) = n x^{n-1}.$

The sequence $g_n$ has no uniformly convergent subsequence.

---

So it seems to me that $V$ is not a compact operator, when we think of
the range as being $C[0,1]$.

---

This is related to the fact that (as far as I can see), although
$Vf$ is continuous, we can't find an estimate for its continuity based
only on the $L^1$-norm of $f$.  (This is what you pointed out in your
comment on Niki's answer.)  A related fact (I think) is the in the
Riemann--Lebesgue lemma, as far as I understand, we can't find an estimate
for the rate of convergence to zero of the Fourier transform of $f$
depending only on the $L^1$-norm of $f$.

Comment: I showed that $f_n \rightharpoonup f\Rightarrow Vf_n \to Vf$, using that $V$ sends relatively weakly compact sets into relatively norm compact sets. Thx

Comment: @JuanPablo: So you agree that $V$ is not a compact operator, then?  And the proposition is false?  Or am I getting myself confused?

Comment: It's not necessary the operator to be compact to prove the proposition. It's a consequence of the property I putted above.

Comment: @JuanPablo: Ah, okay, I was confused about the difference between completely continuous and compact operators.  But am I right that this example shows that Niki's approach via trying to show equicontinuity is flawed?

Comment: @JuanPablo: Okay, I think I now have the definitions straight, and have a proof of the complete continuity.   The basic input is that the dual to $L^1$ is $L^{\infty}$, and that $Vf(t)$ is obtained by integrating against an element of the unit ball in $L^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

I share how I solved it, just for fun

We know that $V:L_1[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ sends relatively weakly compact sets into relatively norm  compact sets. So, we want to show that $V$ sends weakly compact sets into norm compact sets.

I need to recall two important things: Let $X, Y$ be two Banach spaces

- If $X$ is a Banach space and $A\subset X$ is weakly compact, then its closed convex hull is weakly compact.
- If $T:X \to Y$ is a continuous linear operator between two Banach spaces, then it's $\omega- \omega$ continuous.

So, take $(f_n)\subset L_1[0,1]$ sucht that $f_n \rightharpoonup f$. Consider $A=\{f_n\}_n \cup \{f\}$, so $A$ is weakly compact. Thus $co(A)$ is relatively weakly compact. Then $V(co(A))$ is relatively norm compact. As $(Vf_n)\subset V(co(A))$, then it has a convergent subsequence, say $Vf_{n_k} \to g$. Using that $V$ is $\omega- \omega$ continuous, we know that $Vf_{n_k}\rightharpoonup Vf$, then $Vf=g$. And we're done, because we've shown that every subsequence of $(Vf_n)$ has a $\|\cdot\|-$convergent subsequence to $Vf$, which implies that $Vf_n \to Vf$.