# Volterra operator and completely continuous operators

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the Volterra operator $V$ defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914399/volterra-operator-is-completely-continuous/915660#915660). Let me give some definitions first:

> **[Dunford-Pettis]** We say that a bounded linear operator $D:L_1[0,1]\to L_1[0,1]$ is Dunford-Pettis if it sends weakly compact sets into norm compact sets.
>
> **[Representable]** Let $X$ be a Banach space. We say that a bounded linear operator $T:L_1[0,1]\to X$ is representable if there exists $g\in L^{\infty}(\mu,X)$ such that
>   $$
> Tf=\int fg d \mu
> $$
>   for all $f\in L_1[0,1]$.

Note that the last integral is the Bochner integral.

So, I want to show the following

> **Proposition:** Let $D$ be a Dunford-Pettis (D-P in short) operator. Then $V \circ D$ is representable.

I know that if $V \circ D$ is weakly compact, as it has separable range, then it is representable. But it doesn't seem the good idea, because we don't know $D$.

J. Bourgain showed this in *Dunford-Pettis operators on $L_1$ and the Radon-Nikodym property, Israel J. Math. 37(1980), 34-47.*, but I couldn't find it. I'd appreciate if you  say me how he proved it or give me any ideas.

Thanks in advanced